# process took long then gives error "This page isn’t working <ssh-server-ip-address> didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization, ssh, server

So I have this CI Project that converts from database into CSV.

Deployed in a SSH server.

I try to load all data(It's over 2,000,000+) then convert it to CSV.

My first try I filter it with rows having only emails(so it gives me 66,000+ data.)

It successfully exported the data into csv(took a bit of time).

But when I finally try to export all data, after I click the "Convert to CSV", It will take so much time loading and the browser give error:

```
This page isn’t working

<server-ip-address> didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Does this have something to matter with the server?

I tried changing settings in the `/etc/php.ini` with these settings:

```
max_execution_time = 259200
max_input_time = 259200
memory_limit = 300M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

But it still gives me same error.

How can I resolve this? Please help.|

**UPDATE**: I include my code for the csv download, here it is:

```
public function convcsv(){

        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        set_time_limit(0);

        $prefKey = $this->session->flashdata('prefKey');
        $searchKey = $this->session->flashdata('searchKey');
        $withEmail = $this->session->flashdata('withEmail');
        log_message('debug', 'CONVCSV prefKey = ' . $prefKey);
        log_message('debug', 'CONVCSV searchKey = ' . $searchKey);
        $list = $this->user_model->get_users($prefKey, $searchKey, $withEmail, "", "");
        log_message('debug', 'Fetched data');
        $headerArray = array("id", "prefecture_id", "industry_id", "offset", "name", "email");

        // Header
        $header = str_replace(",", "", $headerArray);
        $datas = implode(',', $header) . "\r\n";

        // Body
        foreach($list as $body)
        {
            // 配列の内容を「,」区切りで連結する
            $orig_email = $body['email'];

            $mstring = preg_replace("/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/",',',$orig_email);

            preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $mstring, $matches);
            $email = implode($matches[0]);
            //$email = $matches[0];

            $datas .= $body["id"].",".$body["prefecture_id"].",".$body["industry_id"].",".$body["offset"].",".preg_replace('/[,]/',' ',$body["name"]).",".$email."\r\n";
        }

        // 文字コード返還
        $datas = mb_convert_encoding($datas, "SJIS-win", "UTF-8");

        // ダウンロード開始
        $csvFileName = "phpList_" . date('Ymd_His') . ".csv";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $csvFileName);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        while (ob_get_level() > 0)
        {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        ob_start();
        print trim($datas);
        ob_flush();
        ob_end_clean();
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: do you have to download via a browser, ftp is more efficent

Comment: @nogad not an option. It's from a codeigniter project that converts data to csv.

Comment: your serving a file? or a data stream? considered zipping the file?

Comment: @nogad files. not recommended but I will try the zip option.

Comment: you have to send the  CSV data directly to the output line by line, that way it sort of "streams"  use `$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');` and `fputcsv($f, $data)` and hope for the best.  may also have to do some stuff with flushing the output buffer.  This is actually slower as it uses more network traffic, but it sends smaller packets to the browser.  I've done this for CSV files in the Gigabyte range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will try to explain this as best i can with what little data you gave.  I will assume you can pull the data from the database.  If not you can use `unbuffered` queries in PDO ( I only use PDO for last 4-5 years )

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

As a side note, I've pulled 110 million rows from MySql using unbuffered queries, this is on a server with `56GB` of ram though ( Azure standard_A8, it's pretty l33t ).

For outputting the data, typically when the browser loads a page it "builds" it all server side and then dumps it in one go on the browser (generally speaking).  In your case this is too much data.  So,

(Psudo ish  Code )

```
 set_time_limit(-1); //set time limit.

 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

 $f = fopen('php:\\output', 'w');
 while( false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC) ) ){
    fputcsv($f, $row);
    flush();
 }
```

The disadvantage is there is no real way to tell the download file size before hand.  We are basically sending the download headers, then dumping each line into the output stream and flushing it to the browser one line at a time.

Overall this is slower then doing it in one push, because there is more network traffic but it manages memory better, sometimes it is what it is.

You can see some example on the page ( for streaming output )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

And you might have to use some stuff like this (first) if it doesn't work,

```
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
```

The download should start pretty much instantly though, but there is no guarantee that the complete file will be output as an error part way through could prematurely end the script.

You may have issues with this too `memory_limit = 300M`, I'm spoiled and have `2GB` as the default and up to `6GB` at run time `ini_set('memory_limit', '300M'); //set at runtime`

Lastly, I feel compelled to say not to set the time limit globally but instead do it this way `set_time_limit(-1);` at run time. That way it only affects this script and not the server as a whole.  However you may run into issues with timeouts in apache itself.  It's a very tricky thing because there are a lot of moving parts between the server and the browser.  Many of which can depend on the server, the servers OS, the browser etc. ( environment )

Ideally you would do this though FTP download, but this is probably the best solution ( at least in concept ), it's just a matter of sending easily digestible chunks.